# Форматировать из миллисекунд в дату JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, дата, форматирование

Вытаскиваю с помощью $.get json с удаленного ресурса, с него вытаскиваю дату в миллисекундах, после нужно ее преобразовать в дату формата дд.мм.гггг

Пробую так, выдает NaN.NaN.NaN

```js
var date = new Date(data.list[i].date);
date = date.getDate() + '.' + date.getMonth()+1 + '.' + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Выведите, для начала, содержимое `data.list[i].date`. Возможно там дата в не валидном формате.

Comment: Там значение миллисекунд(или секунд), например 1475757129

Comment: В таком случае, проблемы в коде нет. У меня все работает.

Comment: Это я невнимателен, не преобразовал в число, то что из json вытащил

Comment: Если будет не `Number` - вылетит ошибка.

Comment: @Other, не вылетит, просто создаст объект _Invalid Date_

Comment: @Grundy, угу, правда всё равно работать не будет, так что...